# Excel like indexing in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, matrix, indexing

I have written a function that converts excel like indexing (A34) into JS indexing (array[0][33]).

But it doesn't seem to work when the column name is more complex (e.g. AA).

This is the code I have so far

```
function excel_index(address) {
  let col = address.charCodeAt(0)-65;
  let row = address.substring(1)-1;
  return this[row][col];
}

Array.prototype.excel = excel_index;
```

Comment: You are writing `.charCodeAt(0)`, so why should you expect that `"AA1"` would work ? you are only account for the first character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with base 36 and a correction of 9 (this gets only the value of letters) for the value and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for geting the whole number of letters.

The factor of 26 is the length of the alphabet and a letter more left has a place value of times 26.

```js
function excel_index(address) {
    var col = address.match(/[A-Z]+/)[0],
        row = address.match(/\d+/i)[0];

    return {
        col: col.split('').reduce((r, a) => r * 26 + parseInt(a, 36) - 9, 0) - 1,
        row: row - 1
    };
}

console.log(excel_index('A1'));
console.log(excel_index('AA33'));
console.log(excel_index('ZZ42'));
```

Comment: 26 letters (A-Z), `parseInt(x,36)` means on a base of `36`, and then ignoring the first 10, because they are numeric (that accounts for the `-9`)

Comment: Note that `"99AA"` would yield the same result as `"AA99"`, this is not exactly excel like behaviour, but nice solution

Comment: op can include some sanity checks before.